# Laravel lock some folders on host

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

Guys I have created my first **Laravel Project** and I uploaded it to the server successfully and everything works perfect.

But I can write in the url `www.mydomain.com/resources/views` and show all my views!

Also user can open my **.env** file and view my database connection info!

I want only the user to navigate only to my routes not to any folder he guess.

Comment: How did you deploy your laravel application to the server. Normally if your laravel application has been deployed successfully then you should get error while trying to visit `www.mydomain.com/resources/views` if you are still being able to see the directory listing then there is configuration error. What server are you using `Apache` or `Nginx` ?

Comment: I am using apache. Can you tell me the right deploy method please?

Comment: I am using Bluehost and InmotionHosting

Comment: Do you have SSH access to your server ?

Answer (score 0):

Basic Instruction to Deploy Laravel to shared hosting7

- You should point your document root to `app/public/`
- run `composer install` in the project root directory
- set writable permissions to bootstrap cache `chmod 777 bootstrap/cache`
- set writable permissions to storage `chmod 777 storage -R`

There are many things that can go wrong while deploying application. So, it would be easier for us to help you, if you also provide us step by step process that you followed while deploying the laravel application.

Answer (score 0):

For securing your routes and `.env` file you need to get into your hosting root directory, create `.htaccess` file and copy the below code and paste it in there

```
# Disable index view
Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "\.env$">
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

I hope this will solve your problem.